# Why is there a glMatrixMode in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I just don't understand what OpenGL's `glMatrixMode` is for.

As far as I can see, when `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` is called, it 
is followed by `glVertex`, `glTranslate`, `glRotate` and the like,
that is, OpenGL commands that *place* some objects somewhere in
the space. On the other hand, if `glOrtho` or `glFrustum` or `gluProjection`
is called (ie how the placed objects are *rendered*), it has a preceeding call of `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)`.

I guess what I have written so far is an assumption on which someone will prove
me wrong, but is not the *point* of using different *Matrix Mode*s exactly
because there are different kinds of gl-functions: those concerned with
placing objects and those with how the objects are rendered?

Comment: Do note that this has now been deprecated and you should use shaders and explicit uniforms only, starting from OpenGL 3.1. For instance, OpenGL ES 2.0 does not support glMatrixMode() and similar at all. (Well, of course unless you have a lot of code that does this and/or need to support old hardware/drivers.)

Comment: And `glVertex` should have been considered deprecated from OpenGL 1.0 up. :)

Comment: When you mention something as deprecated, please also mention what is the modern replacement, because without that it is not much informative.

Comment: @Kos from OpenGL 1.1 rather. The first alternative — `glDrawArrays` — appeared only then.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is simple and can be answered very briefly:

- Rendering vertices (as in `glVertex` ) depends on the **current state** of matrices called **"model-view matrix"** and **"projection matrix"**;
- The commands `glTranslatef`, `glPushMatrix`, `glLoadIdentity`, `glLoadMatrix`, `glOrtho`, `gluPerspective` and the whole family affect **the current matrix** (which is either of the above);
- The command `glMatrixMode` **selects the matrix** (model-view or projection) which is affected by the forementioned commands.

(There's also the texture matrix used for texture coordinates, but it's seldomly used.)

So the common use case is:

- Have the model-view matrix active most of the time;
- Whenever you have to initialize the projection matrix (usually at the beginning or when the window is resized, perhaps), switch the active to projection, set up a perspective, and revert back to model-view.

Comment: You should always re-set (i.e. reset a new) the projection matrix everytime you go through through a full display pass. You'll have to use several different projections for any real world application anyway. For example for rendering a HUD in a game you'd use some other projection, than for the scene proper. OpenGL doesn't know "initialization" other than obtaining the context, so please forget about doing one time stuff somewhere, or doing that stupid pattern setting the projection in the reshape handler.

Comment: @datenwolf - True, but push/popMatrix on the projection matrix for 2D overlays works just as well, so it's not really a big difference.

Comment: Weird thing is that I cannot imagine how `glOrtho` or `gluPerspective` could be used for anything else than the projection matrix, and `glTranslate`, `glRotate` & other transforms to be used for projection matrix, so why don't the functions for setting up the projection select the projection matrix internally? It would save the users some headache and be more idiot-proof, I guess. The functions which can be called on either matrix, could still use the mode selection as before.

Comment: this video helps one understand the intuitive representation of model-view-projection matrices.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQNU5XICGvw

Answer (score 4):

You can use glRotate and glTranslate for projection matrices as well.

Also: OpenGL supports transforms of textures and colors. If you active this feature you can for example modify the texture coordinates of an object without rewriting the texture coordinates each frame (slow).

This is a very useful feature if you want to scroll a texture across an object. All you have to do for this is to draw the textured object, set the matrix mode to GL_TEXTURE and call glTranslate to set the offset into the texture.

Comment: Also, projective texture matrices come in use with shadows and projected textures (stage spotlights, headlights, disco, film projectors, etc) ...

Answer (score 3):

As Nils pointed out, you do have more to matrices than just what you mentioned.

I'll add a couple thoughts:

- OpenGL core (from 3.1 onwards) does away with all the matrix stuff completely, so does GL ES 2.0. This is simply due to the fact that shader programs removed much of the requirement of having them exposed at the GL level (it's still a convenience, though). You then only have uniforms, and you have to compute their value completely on the client side.
- There are more matrix manipulation entrypoints than the ones you mention. Some of them apply equally well to projection/modelview (glLoadIdentity/glLoadMatrix/glMultMatrix, Push/Pop), They are very useful if you want to perform the matrix computation yourself (say because you need them somewhere else in your application).

Comment: "Does away with all this matrix stuff" is not really accurate.  Matrix multiplication is still the way of applying transformations to vertex coordinates.  The difference is that it's no longer a fixed function in the pipeline, but fully controlled by programmable shaders.

Answer (score 2):

All geometry coordinates undergo several linear transformations in sequence.  While any linear transformation can be expressed by a single matrix, often you want to think of a sequence of transformations and edit the sequence, and if you have only a single matrix you could only change the ends of that sequence.  By providing several transformation steps, OpenGL gives you several places in the middle where you can change the transformation as well.

Calling `glMatrixMode` before emitting geometry has no effect at all.  You call `glMatrixMode` before editing the transform matrix, to determine where in the overall sequence those edits appear.

(NB: Looking at the sequence makes a lot more sense if you remember that translation and rotation are not commutative, because translation changes the center of rotation.  Similarly translation and scaling are not commutative.)