# Why does glMatrixMode exist?

Tags: opengl

Why does OpenGL distinguish GL_MODELVIEW matrix and GL_PROJECTION matrix using glMatrixMode?

I mean, why does it bother to devide the matrix into two?

It seems ok to calculate all(including the modelview matrix and the projection matrix) in  one matrix.

Comment: It's possibly just poorly named. There are two matrix stacks. The mode is the state of editing either one. I.e. `glTranslatef` or `glPushMatrix` will affect the matrix stack given by the last call to `glMatrixMode`. There are two for reasons best understood when you start writing shaders and doing your own lighting calculations. Lighting can't be performed after the perspective divide because the space is distorted, and it's common (but not a rule) to perform lighting in eye space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I just don't get why there is a glMatrixMode in OpenGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566558/i-just-dont-get-why-there-is-a-glmatrixmode-in-opengl)

Comment: Projection matrix is for defining the "lens" of the virtual camera, the modelview for the rest. The distinction is important for any calculations that depend on transformation of *directions* (as opposed to positions), because directions must be transformed by the transposed inverse of the modelview matrix (and only the modelview matrix); pulling in the projection will produce wrong results; the mostly affects things like illumination and reflection vector calculations.

Comment: Anyhow,it is deprecated.Use your own matrices and shaders.